# Add number of pages to datatables manually?

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables, datatables-1.10

Currently, I am working with Datatables 1.10.9. Currently, the table can have hundreds of values. We don't want to load all data at once. We want to use the defer loading of the data.

For example, default we will show 50 data, and click on the second page we will load the values for the next 50. So based on the page click we will upload the table.

Rest call is also configured such that "startat=51, count=50". So the server will return values based on that.

But our problem is on initially Rest call will be sent as "startat=1, count=50".

Rest call returns 50 data and also the total number of data for a particular thing.

So the table will be upload 50 data, and pagination is showing only one page.

But the pagination should show based on the total number of values. As of now, Datatable is showing pagination based on the array data.

But we need to assign the pagination manually based on the total values received.

So please help us to achieve this?

I tried to use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "scripts/server_processing.php",
        "deferLoading": 57
    } );
} );
```

But we can't use it as both the row values will be received based on the header values. And the header values are dynamic.

```
var pageLength = 50;
var table= $('#datatable').DataTable({
                    data: valuesArray,
                    "columns": headersArray,
                    "iDisplayLength": pageLength,
                    dom: 'Blfrtip',
                    colReorder: {
                        enable: false
                    },


                });
```

Comment: Can you show sample of your JSON response from server

Comment: Datatables accept response in certain form. You have to change your server response in accordance to the datatables. Or you have to change the `ajax` property of datatables as a function.